# Separating UNIX shell variable from adjacent characters

Tags: bash, shell

I have a unix shell variable, `FOO = "bar"`, which I want to insert in a command directly in front of an underscore. I implemented this like so:

```
$ program.py --in_path ~/dir/$FOO_file_20210607.csv
```

This interprets the variable being dereferenced as `$FOO_file_20210607`, not `$FOO`.

Is there a way to parenthesize `FOO` to isolate it from the following statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$FOO` is shorthand for `${FOO}` when dropping the braces doesn't introduce an ambiguity. Doing so *does* here, so you should keep them.

```
program.py --in_path ~/dir/${FOO}_file_20210607.csv
```

Or, since `$FOO` should be quoted anyway to protect against unexpected word-splitting or pathname expansion, you can simply use quotes, which will also be sufficient to isolate `FOO` as the parameter name as a side effect.

```
program.py --in_path ~/dir/"$FOO"_file_20210607.csv
```